# why does my JS code runs only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my question:

I have an script tag at the end of my document, with this:

```
<script>
    $("#one").css("height",$("#two").width()/2);
</script>
```

And I want it to keep refreshing the code... But it only runs when I refresh the page. What should I do to keep running it?

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: there are multiple ways to do it like using setInterval()... but there could be a better way to do it if you say what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#one").css("height",$("#two").width()/2);
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

This will repeat the function every 1000ms (=1s).

Answer (score 0):

If this is to animate something you can use the jquery .animate

```
$("#one").animate({height:0},1000);
```

this animates the height down to 0 and doing so over 1000 ms. there is plenty of other options with it.